# Forcing OpenLDAP connections to use STARTTLS not allowing user to login

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ldap, openldap

I have a [basic](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-a-basic-ldap-server-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps) OpenLDAP server running on `Ubuntu 16.04LTS` which authenticates users perfectly fine but I really wanted to make it more secure so I decided to use STARTTLS and [How To Encrypt OpenLDAP Connections Using STARTTLS tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-encrypt-openldap-connections-using-starttls) to help make it all happen. Everything went perfectly fine until this point as depicted in the image below:

[image: Part that caused me to not login to the client]

After I did everything that it told me to do in the image above I ran `ssh {user-on-openldap-server@localhost}` it gave me an error message reading:

```sh
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

**Note:** localhost in this case was the client machine where I used this [How To Authenticate Client Computers Using LDAP on an Ubuntu 12.04 VPS tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-authenticate-client-computers-using-ldap-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps) to set it up.

P.S There was a comment on the [How To Encrypt OpenLDAP Connections Using STARTTLS tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-encrypt-openldap-connections-using-starttls?comment=38598) that I used to setup STARTTLS on OpenLDAP where the user seemed to have the same problem that I am having but there is no answer on his comment so that is why I am hoping to give his comment more attention while also helping me.
[image]

When I ran `ldapsearch -H ldap://my-ip -x -b "dc=example,dc=com" -LLL -Z -d1 dn`

Here is the output of that command:

```sh
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldap://my-ip)
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldap://my-ip:389/??base)
ldap_extended_operation_s
ldap_extended_operation
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP my-ip:389
ldap_new_socket: 4
ldap_prepare_socket: 4
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 108.75.66.244:389
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 4 tm: -1 async: 0
attempting to connect: 
connect success
ldap_open_defconn: successful
ldap_send_server_request
ber_scanf fmt ({it) ber:
ber_scanf fmt ({) ber:
ber_flush2: 31 bytes to sd 4
ldap_result ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid 1
wait4msg ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid 1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid 1 all 1
** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Connections:
* host: my-ip  port: 389  (default)
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Wed May 18 23:57:55 2016


** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 1,  origid 1, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x55f5ab064a60 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x55f5ab064a60 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid 1 all 1
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x55f5ab064a60 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid 1 all 1
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 12 contents:
read1msg: ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid 1 message type extended-result
ber_scanf fmt ({eAA) ber:
read1msg: ld 0x55f5ab064a60 0 new referrals
read1msg:  mark request completed, ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid 1
request done: ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid 1
res_errno: 0, res_error: <>, res_matched: <>
ldap_free_request (origid 1, msgid 1)
ldap_parse_extended_result
ber_scanf fmt ({eAA) ber:
ldap_parse_result
ber_scanf fmt ({iAA) ber:
ber_scanf fmt (}) ber:
ldap_msgfree
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_send_server_request
ber_scanf fmt ({it) ber:
ber_scanf fmt ({i) ber:
ber_flush2: 14 bytes to sd 4
ldap_result ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid 2
wait4msg ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid 2 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid 2 all 1
** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Connections:
* host: my-ip  port: 389  (default)
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Wed May 18 23:57:55 2016


** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 2,  origid 2, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x55f5ab064a60 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x55f5ab064a60 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid 2 all 1
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x55f5ab064a60 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid 2 all 1
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 12 contents:
read1msg: ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid 2 message type bind
ber_scanf fmt ({eAA) ber:
read1msg: ld 0x55f5ab064a60 0 new referrals
read1msg:  mark request completed, ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid 2
request done: ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid 2
res_errno: 0, res_error: <>, res_matched: <>
ldap_free_request (origid 2, msgid 2)
ldap_parse_result
ber_scanf fmt ({iAA) ber:
ber_scanf fmt (}) ber:
ldap_msgfree
ldap_search_ext
put_filter: "(objectclass=*)"
put_filter: simple
put_simple_filter: "objectclass=*"
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_send_server_request
ber_scanf fmt ({it) ber:
ber_scanf fmt ({) ber:
ber_flush2: 60 bytes to sd 4
ldap_result ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1
wait4msg ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 all 0
** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Connections:
* host: my-ip  port: 389  (default)
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Wed May 18 23:57:55 2016


** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 3,  origid 3, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x55f5ab064a60 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x55f5ab064a60 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 all 0
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x55f5ab064a60 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 all 0
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 26 contents:
read1msg: ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid 3 message type search-entry
ldap_get_dn_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({ml{) ber:
dn: dc=example,dc=com
ber_scanf fmt ({xx) ber:
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ldap_msgfree
ldap_result ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1
wait4msg ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 all 0
** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Connections:
* host: my-ip  port: 389  (default)
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Wed May 18 23:57:55 2016


** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 3,  origid 3, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x55f5ab064a60 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x55f5ab064a60 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 all 0
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x55f5ab064a60 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 all 0
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 35 contents:
read1msg: ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid 3 message type search-entry

ldap_get_dn_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({ml{) ber:
dn: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
ber_scanf fmt ({xx) ber:
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ldap_msgfree
ldap_result ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1
wait4msg ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 all 0
** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Connections:
* host: my-ip  port: 389  (default)
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Wed May 18 23:57:55 2016


** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 3,  origid 3, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x55f5ab064a60 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x55f5ab064a60 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 all 0
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x55f5ab064a60 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 all 0
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 36 contents:
read1msg: ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid 3 message type search-entry

ldap_get_dn_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({ml{) ber:
dn: ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
ber_scanf fmt ({xx) ber:
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ldap_msgfree
ldap_result ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1
wait4msg ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 all 0
** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Connections:
* host: my-ip  port: 389  (default)
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Wed May 18 23:57:55 2016


** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 3,  origid 3, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x55f5ab064a60 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x55f5ab064a60 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 all 0
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x55f5ab064a60 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 all 0
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 35 contents:
read1msg: ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid 3 message type search-entry

ldap_get_dn_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({ml{) ber:
dn: ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
ber_scanf fmt ({xx) ber:
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ldap_msgfree
ldap_result ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1
wait4msg ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 all 0
** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Connections:
* host: my-ip  port: 389  (default)
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Wed May 18 23:57:55 2016


** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 3,  origid 3, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x55f5ab064a60 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x55f5ab064a60 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 all 0
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x55f5ab064a60 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 all 0
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 45 contents:
read1msg: ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid 3 message type search-entry

ldap_get_dn_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({ml{) ber:
dn: cn=admin,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
ber_scanf fmt ({xx) ber:
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ldap_msgfree
ldap_result ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1
wait4msg ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 all 0
** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Connections:
* host: my-ip  port: 389  (default)
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Wed May 18 23:57:55 2016


** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 3,  origid 3, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x55f5ab064a60 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x55f5ab064a60 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 all 0
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x55f5ab064a60 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 all 0
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 43 contents:
read1msg: ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid 3 message type search-entry

ldap_get_dn_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({ml{) ber:
dn: cn=irc,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
ber_scanf fmt ({xx) ber:
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ldap_msgfree
ldap_result ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1
wait4msg ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 all 0
** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Connections:
* host: my-ip  port: 389  (default)
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Wed May 18 23:57:55 2016


** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 3,  origid 3, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x55f5ab064a60 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x55f5ab064a60 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 all 0
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x55f5ab064a60 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 all 0
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 44 contents:
read1msg: ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid 3 message type search-entry

ldap_get_dn_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({ml{) ber:
dn: cn=user,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
ber_scanf fmt ({xx) ber:
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ldap_msgfree
ldap_result ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1
wait4msg ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 all 0
** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Connections:
* host: my-ip  port: 389  (default)
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Wed May 18 23:57:55 2016


** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 3,  origid 3, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x55f5ab064a60 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x55f5ab064a60 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 all 0
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x55f5ab064a60 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 all 0
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 47 contents:
read1msg: ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid 3 message type search-entry

ldap_get_dn_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({ml{) ber:
dn: cn=ftp-alex,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
ber_scanf fmt ({xx) ber:
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ldap_msgfree
ldap_result ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1
wait4msg ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 all 0
** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Connections:
* host: my-ip  port: 389  (default)
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Wed May 18 23:57:55 2016


** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 3,  origid 3, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x55f5ab064a60 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x55f5ab064a60 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 all 0
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x55f5ab064a60 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 all 0
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 50 contents:
read1msg: ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid 3 message type search-entry

ldap_get_dn_ber
ber_scanf fmt ({ml{) ber:
dn: cn=ftp-spencer,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
ber_scanf fmt ({xx) ber:
ldap_get_attribute_ber
ldap_msgfree
ldap_result ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1
wait4msg ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 all 0
** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Connections:
* host: my-ip  port: 389  (default)
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Wed May 18 23:57:55 2016


** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 3,  origid 3, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x55f5ab064a60 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x55f5ab064a60 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x55f5ab064a60 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 all 0
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x55f5ab064a60 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid -1 all 0
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 12 contents:
read1msg: ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid 3 message type search-result
ber_scanf fmt ({eAA) ber:
read1msg: ld 0x55f5ab064a60 0 new referrals
read1msg:  mark request completed, ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid 3
request done: ld 0x55f5ab064a60 msgid 3
res_errno: 0, res_error: <>, res_matched: <>
ldap_free_request (origid 3, msgid 3)

ldap_parse_result
ber_scanf fmt ({iAA) ber:
ber_scanf fmt (}) ber:
ldap_msgfree
ldap_free_connection 1 1
ldap_send_unbind
ber_flush2: 7 bytes to sd 4
ldap_free_connection: actually freed
```

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: Is `pam_ldap` or `sssd` set to use STARTTLS for its ldap connections?

Comment: @84104 How would I check if it is or is no set???

Comment: By looking at the config files for the relevant services.

Comment: @84104 I think it is enabled but I am not positive. Is there a definite way to figure it out.

Comment: By looking at the config files for the relevant services.

Comment: @84104 I just edited the question with some details that may or may not help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This was a very simple fix where I just had to install `libpam-ldapd` on the client side instead of installing `libpam-ldap` on the client side. Once I ran that it gave me the option to use `starttls`.